# useCallback does not inherit parent props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm detecting keypresses in a component that is aware of what dialog component is currently open elsewhere in the app via a prop, **currentDialog**. Normally I'd be able to access this prop in a nested function but it seems this isn't possible when using `useCallback`:

```
export const AllAreaNav = (props) => {

    console.log('AllAreaNav / props.currentDialog: ', props.currentDialog); // displays correct dialog

    const handleKeyPress = useCallback((event) => {

        console.log('AllAreaNav / handleKeyPress / props.currentDialog: ', props.currentDialog); // displays undefined
        
        if(event.keyCode === 70) {
            //Do whatever when F is pressed
            console.log("F key pressed");
            if (props.currentDialog == "DialogSearchBar") {
                // Take action based on DialogSearchBar being active
            } else {
                // Take action based on DialogSearchBar NOT being active
            }

        }

    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        // Listener for keypresses
        document.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyPress, false);
        return () => {
            document.removeEventListener("keydown", handleKeyPress, false);
        };
    }, []);

    return (
        {jsxElements}
    )
};
```

So now I'm a little unsure of a straightforward way of passing this as a parameter - assuming this would be the next step. From researching I believe it's fine to add another parameter alongside **event**? That this should work as I intend:

```
const handleKeyPress = useCallback((event, currentDialog) => {
```

However, I'm not entirely sure of how to initially pass this to the function. If I modify the listener to be:

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyPress(event, props.currentDialog, false);
```

I'm unsure if this is correct, or where exactly to define **event** in this context, in the manner `handleKeyPress` defaults its as a parameter.

Comment: When I put `props.currentDialog` in both dependency arrays, it works as expected.

Comment: You have closures on `props.currentDialog == "DialogSearchBar"` ... because of empty `[]`, there should be a warning in your IDE, check what it says.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you were trying to resolve the problem by parametrizing the callback but you did not have an event in your context. In order to parametrize AND have the event in context, you must create a closure on the `currentDialog` parameter.

You can try this solution:

```
/**
 * move callback definition outside the component
 * and create a closure on currentDialog (function returning a function)
 */
const handleKeyPress = (currentDialog) => (event) => {
  if (event.keyCode === 70) {
    //Do whatever when F is pressed
    console.log("F key pressed");
    if (currentDialog == "DialogSearchBar") {
      // Take action based on DialogSearchBar being active
    } else {
      // Take action based on DialogSearchBar NOT being active
    }
  }
};

export const AllAreaNav = (props) => {
  console.log("AllAreaNav / props.currentDialog: ", props.currentDialog); // displays correct dialog

  useEffect(() => {
    // Listener for keypresses
    const listener = handleKeyPress(props.currentDialog); // use closure to create a callback closured on currentDialog value
    document.addEventListener(
      "keydown",
      listener,
      false
    );
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener(
        "keydown",
        listener,
        false
      );
    };
  }, [handleKeyPress, props.currentDialog]); // pass callback and currentDialog value to dependency array

  return { jsxElements };
};
```